# Why do I get the wrong answer when determining the charge in a capacitor using definition of voltage?

Tags: capacitor, charge

I want to determine the charge in a capacitor. I didn't remember the formula for it, \$Q = C \cdot V\$, so I tried to derive it. This is how I went forwards. I've made the assumption that the capacitor has no initial charge.
\$v = \frac{dw}{dq} \Leftrightarrow dw = v \space dq \Rightarrow \int dw = \int v \space dq \Rightarrow w = v \space q\$.

Since the energy stored in a capacitor is \$w = \frac{1}{2} C v_c^2\$, I tried to plug this in which results in the equation for charge: \$q = \frac{1}{2} C v_c\$.

This is half of the expected value, so where it the faulty logic here?

---

If I start by using the definition of current, I get the correct equation:

\$i = \frac{dq}{dt} \Leftrightarrow dq = i \space dt \$

\$i_c = C \frac{dv_c}{dt} \Leftrightarrow i_c \space dt = C \space dv_c\$

\$dq = C \space dv_c \Rightarrow q = C \space v_c\$

Comment: Oh no... this "half of energy" thing again..

Comment: \$v\$ is not a constant, so your integral of \$ v\:dq\$ is wrong.

Comment: @Chu Of course! Silly me, there had to be something wrong with the math. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

May as well document what Chu pointed out:

$$\begin{align*}
\textrm{d} w &= v\:\textrm{d} q&  Q&=C\: V\\
&\therefore\\
\int \textrm{d} w &= \int_0^Q v\:\textrm{d} q\\\\
W &= \int_0^Q v\:\textrm{d} q &
 &=\int_0^Q \frac{q}{C}\:\textrm{d} q\\\\
&= \frac{1}{C} \int_0^Q q\:\textrm{d} q &
&= \frac{1}{C} \left[\frac{1}{2}q^2\right]\bigg|_0^Q\\\\
&= \frac{1}{C} \left[\frac{1}{2}Q^2\right] &
&= \frac{1}{C} \left[\frac{1}{2}C^2V^2\right]\\\\
&= \frac{1}{2} C \: V^2
\end{align*}$$

That's the work/energy stored on a capacitor.